# Discord bot check if message author is offline

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that checks every message sent in a server to see if the message author is appearing offline.
If the message author is appearing offline, it should delete their message and send one back telling them that the can't send messages when offline.

I have approached this 2 ways, the first way always says that the user is offline and deletes their message regardless of the status and the 2nd way just errors.

**Attempt 1:**

This attempt always deleted the users message and told them they were offline. The `user.status` would always return "offline".

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    user = message.author
    if user.status == discord.Status.offline:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention}, you cannot send messages while offline.")

    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Attempt 2:**

This attempt gave the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status'` to `user.status` and `user` would return `None`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    user_id = message.author.id
    user = bot.get_user(user_id)

    if user.status == discord.Status.offline:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention}, you cannot send messages while offline.")

    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to enable and import the presence and member Intent

Comment: Don't think "User" has a "Status" method. you're thinking about "Member". You will need to convert user to member by searching the "Guild" with the user.id

Comment: @Dominik How do I import the presence and member Intent?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Can you explain how to convert the user to a member by searching the "Guild" with the user.id?

Comment: @JohnSmith Same way you imported `intents.message_content = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some logical errors in your code.

We can use the `on_message` event, define the `message` argument as `message: discord.Message` and work with this one to retrieve the data.

**Here is a revised code:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True # Import the Members Intent
intents.presences = True # Import the Presence Intent to check the status

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.TextChannel): # Making sure the message is not a DM to the bot
        member = message.guild.get_member(message.author.id)
        if member and member.status == discord.Status.offline:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f"{member.mention}, you cannot send messages while offline.")

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

In this code, we have an additional check to not listen to direct messages to the bot. This can be removed if you want to.

- We get the `member` by using `message.guild.get_member(message.author.id)` instead of relying on the bot as you did
- We import the Presence and Members Intent in order to work with the member and its presence properly. Make sure to turn them on in the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)